# BASH - Include line feeds in message output

Tags: bash, command, linefeed

I'm using the following command to capture the diskspace used on my server and store it in the var space.

```
space=`cd /users/; du -hs * | sort -h;`
```

at the command line entering `echo "$space"` shows the correct output with the line feeds for the results.

I'm now trying to email this to myself, the email sends fine but the du output all appears on one line not new lines like it does at the bash prompt.

This is my mail body and how I'm trying to use `space`.

It works, but the output is not showing as it would when run from the command line.

```
mailbody="$server_name - Server disk usage is at ${current_usage}. ${space}"
```

eg. I get

```
Test Server - Server disk usage is at 40%. 1.1G jon 1.1G paul 1.9G ringo
```

where I'd like to get

```
Test Server - Server disk usage is at 40%. 
1.1G jon 
1.1G paul 
1.9G ringo
```

Any idea how I can do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you quote `"$mailbody"`?

Comment: I use:   `echo ${mailbody} | mail -s "$server_name" "${mail}" -- -f "${from}"` Should I quote mailbody ?

Comment: @glennjackman thanks changing my echo to `echo -e "${mailbody}"` seems to have fixed it

Answer (score -1):

The solution is:

```
space=$`cd /users/; du -hs * | sort -h;`
```

The $ makes the ansi-c standard codes expanded. Even form feeds and alerts work.

Comment: The problem was missing quoting. You probably mean `$'...'` and not `$\`...\``, no?